# how to view and edit data of a csv file

Tags: batch-file

I have a csv file records.csv on my desktop

I want to view name and marks and condition if failed or pass ... But I'm stuck .. I only have marks and condition working fine but I can't see any possible way to view name of person since I'm using the /f switch in my for loop

This are the contents of the csv  file

```
name,age,gender,exam total marks
david,10,m,100
frank,28,m,400
dennis,32,m,243
Edwin,22,m,213
sarah,23,f,119
```

Here's my code so far

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEdelayedEXPANSION
color 0a
for /f " skip=1 tokens=4,*delims=," %%a in (records.csv) do (
  if "%%a" gtr "200" (
    set condition=pass
  ) else (
    set condition=fail
  ) 
  set "cof=%%a---!%%a:  !condition! !"
  echo !cof!
)
echo.
pause
```

Please help me out 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
for /f " skip=1 tokens=1,4 delims=," %%a in (records.csv) do (
  if 0%%b gtr 200 (
  ....
  )
  echo %%a---!condition!
)
```

%%a is the first used token (1=name), %%b is the second used token (4=points)

Note: if you use `if "%%b" gtr "200"` you will compare strings. So `95` would be greater than `200`

However without the `"` it would fail, if the points are missing in the table. To avoid that, I don't check `if %%b ...` but `if 0%%b ...`

Comment: Thanks.. I believe that would solve the problem ...I don't know why I didnt think of that before: :)

Comment: It's always the small, genious things, you don't think of (see my edit)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked ..Seems to work without the zero ....what's it for please explain logic part of it ......

Comment: if `%%b` is empty (points are missing in your csv) then `if %%b ...` will give a syntax error. With the `0` it is avoided (and it doesn't disturb if `%%b` is not empty)

Comment: Again ..: I couldn't have thought of that